# Need to get X by itself, have to rationalize the denominator

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{100000x }{ \sqrt{196 + x^2}} = 50,000$$

I cannot figure out how to get rid of the square root so I can isolate the $x$. Can anyone give me a hint or lead me into the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: You could square both sides.

Comment: And also, divide both sides by 50,000 first.

Comment: Cancel $50000$ to make things less ugly. We get $\frac{2x}{\sqrt{196+x^2}}=1$. Multiply through by $\sqrt{196+x^2}$. We get $2x=\sqrt{196+x^2}$. Square both sides. Note that squaring can introduce extraneous roots.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{100000x }{ \sqrt{196 + x^2}} = 50,000$$

$$\frac{2x }{ \sqrt{196 + x^2}} = 1$$

Multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{196 + x^2}$, we have

$$2x  = \sqrt{196 + x^2}$$

$$(2x)^2  = (\sqrt{196 + x^2})^2$$

$$4x^2  = 196 + x^2$$

$$3x^2 = 196$$

$$x^2 = \frac{196}{3}$$

$$x = \pm \sqrt{ \frac{196}{3}}$$

Plug it back in and check to test for extraneous solutions. You never know, you might find one (you will).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You have, for a general expression,
$$\dfrac{ax}{\sqrt{b+x^2}}=c\\
\implies a^2x^2=bc^2+c^2x^2\\
\implies x=\sqrt{\dfrac{bc}{a^2-c^2}}$$